# How can i remove Bulk unwanted image label

Tags: magento-1.9, error

How can i remove 1000 products unwanted image label from single step.

[image]

Comment: Where from you need to remove describe more

Comment: from admin panel or anything.

Comment: why these duplicate labels occured, may i know the reason

Comment: make sure we r  still connected

Comment: Click Remove images under Remove column then Save

Comment: how can i use for no.of  products.

Comment: how can i removed 100 products like same error,  is any excel format is avail to remove that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom script to delete labels. Use following code to serve the purpose:

```
$image= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();
$_images = $image->getItemByColumnValue('label','YOUR_LABEL');
```

Comment: Could you give me a brief description..

Comment: with the use of above code, you need to fetch the row which shows empty label and remove it.